# Performance Optimizing ParametricFunction

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, parametric-functions

Setting up the system:

```
eqs = {a'[t] == -k1 a[t] b[t], b'[t] == -k1 a[t] b[t], 
       c'[t] == k1 a[t] b[t] - k2 c[t], d'[t] == k2 c[t] - k3 d[t], 
       e'[t] == k3 d[t]};
initCond = {a[0] == a0, b[0] == 0, c[0] == 0, d[0] == 0, e[0] == 0};
impulse = {WhenEvent[t == t0, b[t] -> b[t] + bAdded, 
                     "LocationMethod" -> "LinearInterpolation"]};
addeq = {Fa[t] == epsa a[t], Fc[t] == epsc c[t], Fd[t] == epsd d[t], 
         Fe[t] == epse e[t], Ftot[t] == Fa[t] + Fc[t] + Fd[t] + Fe[t]};
tDepVars = {a, b, c, d, e, Fa, Fc, Fd, Fe, Ftot};
fixedParams = SetPrecision[{a0 -> 1, epsa -> 0.16, bAdded -> 1, t0 -> 100}, 30];
varParams = Keys[initGuesses];
```

Finding a parametric solution:

```
solution = ParametricNDSolve[Join[eqs, initCond, addeq, impulse] /. fixedParams,
           tDepVars, {t, 0, 500}, varParams, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
```

Sometimes this solution is quick, and sometimes extremely slow.

```
variableGuess[var_] := SetPrecision[{k1 -> 0.09, k2 -> var, k3 -> 0.00025, epsc -> 2.6, 
                       epsd -> 2.1, epse -> 2.6}, 30];
result = Table[{10^i, AbsoluteTiming[((Ftot /. solution) @@ 
               (Values[variableGuess[10^i]]))[t]]}, {i, -5, 3}];
ListLogLogPlot[Transpose@{result[[All, 1]], result[[All, 2, 1]]}]
```

[image]

In some critical cases for me, the length of time it takes to find the solution is timing out `Dynamic` stuff that all of this is operating within.

Any suggestions for performance improvements?